# How to use ndk-build build the source files in different folders?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I know that to build so file, I should put the source file in /jni/ folder.
But how can I build separate so in different folders.

For example, the structure of my project:

```
/jni/Android.mk
/jni/submodule1/Android.mk
/jni/submodule1/sub1.c
/jni/submodule2/Android.mk
/jni/submodule2/sub2.c
```

I have tried to write this in Android.mk in the top level:

```
$(LOCAL_PATH) :=$(call all-makefiles-under)
```

then wrote make info in Android.mk in submodule

the error is:

```
ndk-build 
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/../workspace/jni/sub.c', needed b
y `/home/../workspace/obj/local/armeabi/objs/submodule/sub.o'.  Stop.
```

Can someone give me a solution? Thank you!

Update 1:
The code of Android.mk in submoudle:

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)

 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sub.c 

 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)

 LOCAL_MODULE := sub
 LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog
 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libc

 LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_OPTIONAL_EXECUTABLES)
 LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
 include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

SOLVED:

I should use ndk-build in the root directory, but not in jni directory. Thanks all of you!

Comment: You need to add submodule Android.mk codes as well.

Comment: @user2359247 Yes, I have added the Android.mk in the submodule. And it contains the build info. Update the Android in the submodule.

Comment: why don't you just use "include $(LOCAL_PATH)/submodule1/Android.mk" in your main Android.mk inside main module?

Answer (score 1):

You should try `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` rather then `$(LOCAL_PATH) :=$(call all-makefiles-under)` in main `Android.mk` and make folder under  jni folder with there separate c files and  `Android.mk`  files

Comment: I have tried the all-subdir-makefiles. The errors also appeared. I have updated the Android.mk in subfolder. Is there anything wrong with the Android.mk?

Comment: @Bob are you using MAC or Linux ?

Comment: check whether you have given Read-Write  permission to your project folder .

Comment: Yes, I have RW permission.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /submodule1/sub1.c
```

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `/home/../workspace/jni/submodule//submodule/sub.c', needed b
y `/home/../workspace/obj/local/armeabi/objs//submodule/sub.o'.  Stop.

Comment: Could you please try this one